# Fable 3 replayable quests

Tags: fable-3

So I just finished the new DLC for Fable 3 and completed all the quests available. After finishing the DLC I decided to tie up any loose ends in mainland albion. For example kill/find the gnomes, Keys etc.. However I noticed quests like the wheel of misfortune and day at the chicken races (both repeatable quests) have a set number of guild seals assigned to them. For example if you look at your quests you will see a 40 next to wheel of misfortune and 10 next to day at the chicken races. I have beat both of them once, but don't see a need to do them again unless it will clear them from my quest list and give me the feeling of completeness I desire. Is there something special you have to do to receive those guild seals or remove the quest from the quest list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, all repeatable quests always stay in your quest list. This is kind of annoying (since it is harder to keep track of what quests you've already finished), but it was probably done this way so that it is easy to find them again, if the player wants to run the quest again.

Comment: Well that kinda sucks. Although I can see how it would be useful to get back to the quest if you were in to chicken racing :P. I just wish there was someway to get those 40 or 10 guild seals.